# Cordova - make the app stay in immersive mode even after using the keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, keyboard

my cordova app when you open the keyboard it doesn't scroll up and when you close the android keyboard it has the slashes appearing as if you weren't listening in immersive mode even though it was already starting with it. Does anyone know how to solve one or the other problem.
I already installed the cordova plugin keyboard and nothing. tried hideFormAccessoryBar, shrinkView... well
what I want is that after using the keyboard the app stays in immersive mode like before opening it and scrolling so I can type seeing the field.

I already installed the cordova plugin keyboard and nothing. tried hideFormAccessoryBar, shrinkView... well

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android, you can try to add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to the `activity` node of your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I did that but it didn't change when I open the keyboard it comes out of immersive mode and doesn't scroll for digital power the input is hidden. and when you close the keyboard the app has the system bars on it.